# Getting Null Pointer Exception - Using an Interface to Pass Data from an Adapter to a Sub-fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-adapter

I have an `Adapter` and a `Sub-Fragment`. I am using an interface to pass data from the `Adapter` to the `Sub-Fragment`. The problem I am having is that I keep getting a `Null Pointer Exception`. I have read through the various posts here relating to the problem and can't figure out where I went wrong. I get the NPE at the line 'passAdapterVariable.passAdapterVariable(mname)'. Based on what I have read I suspect it may be because I am not properly initializing passAdapterVariable. I have tried initializing it several different ways based on other examples but I keep getting the NPE.

**Here is the Adapter**

```
public class MatchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MatchAdapter.MatchViewHolder> {

    //declaration of variables
    private Fragment fragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private DiscoverPage discoverPage;
    private Context context;
    private int size;
    private int mposition;
    private TextView txt_matchname;
    private ImageView img_matchpic;
    List<String> maImg = new ArrayList<>();
    private String mname;
    PassAdapterVariable passAdapterVariable;


    public interface PassAdapterVariable {

        void passAdapterVariable(String mname);
    }


    //the constructor
    public MatchAdapter(List<String> maImg, int size, Context context, DiscoverPage discoverPage){//, PassAdapterVariable passAdapterVariable) {

        this.maImg = maImg;
        this.context = context;
        this.discoverPage = discoverPage;
        this.size = size;
        //this.passAdapterVariable = (PassAdapterVariable)context;
    }

    public MatchAdapter(String mname, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.passAdapterVariable  = (PassAdapterVariable)context;
    }


    //PassAdapterVariable passAdapterVariable = (PassAdapterVariable) context;


    @Override
    public MatchAdapter.MatchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.match_items, parent, false);
        MatchViewHolder matchViewHolder = new MatchViewHolder(view, maImg, discoverPage);


        return matchViewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MatchViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Picasso.with(context).load(maImg.get(position)).into(holder.img_match);
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return maImg.size();
    }


    //viewholder class
    public class MatchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private static final String TAG = "error";
        //declare variables
        private DiscoverPage discoverPage;
        private ImageView img_match;


        //ViewHolder constructor
        public MatchViewHolder(View itemView, final List<String> maImg, final DiscoverPage discoverPage) {
            super(itemView);

            //initialize variables inside the viewholder constructor
            this.discoverPage = discoverPage;
            img_match = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_match);
            txt_matchname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_matchname);
            img_matchpic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_matchpic);


            //set click listener for the img_match
            img_match.setOnClickListener(this);

        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view == img_match) {
                //discoverPage.isHidden();
                Fragment currentFragment;
                fragment = new ClickedMatch();
                fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack("DiscoverPage");

                if ((currentFragment = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_container)) != null) {
                    transaction.hide(currentFragment);
                }
                else {
                    transaction.commit();
                }


                mname = maImg.get(getAdapterPosition());
                mposition = getAdapterPosition();
                mname = maImg.get(mposition);
                passAdapterVariable.passAdapterVariable(mname);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the Sub-Fragment**

```
public class ClickedMatch extends Fragment implements MatchAdapter.PassAdapterVariable{

    //declare variables
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView txt_matchname;
    private TextView txt_matchprice;
    private ImageView img_matchpic;
    private String mname;
    private String imgmatch;
    List<String> maImg = new ArrayList<>();
    int size;
    Context context;
    DiscoverPage discoverPage;
    private String pname;
    private int i;
    MatchAdapter.PassAdapterVariable passAdapterVariable;



    public ClickedMatch() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clicked_match, container, false);

        //initialize variables
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);//set toolbar as action bar
        txt_matchname = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txt_matchname);
        img_matchpic = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_matchpic);

        //setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        if(((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()!= null){
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        }

       // MatchAdapter matAdapter = new MatchAdapter(maImg, size, context, discoverPage,
        //passAdapterVariable);

       // matAdapter.passAdapterVariable = this;
        //passAdapterVariable.passAdapterVariable(mname);
        //txt_matchname.setText(pname);

        MatchAdapter matAdapter = new MatchAdapter(pname, getContext());
        matAdapter.passAdapterVariable = this;
        passAdapterVariable(pname);
        txt_matchname.setText(pname);

        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void passAdapterVariable(String mname) {
       this.pname = mname;

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            this.getActivity().finish();
        }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

**Here is the error log**

```
08-13 21:53:49.341 12852-12852/com.test.jack E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.test.jack, PID: 12852

     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.test.jack.MatchAdapter$PassAdapterVariable.passAdapterVariable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
     at com.test.jack.MatchAdapter$MatchViewHolder.onClick(MatchAdapter.java:138)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

To add some more context, I have a main activity(UserMainPage). A bottom navigation menu selector replaces the UserMainPage with a fragment(DiscoverPage).

DiscoverPage calls the adapter(MatchAdapter). A button click on DiscoverPage replaces DiscoverPage with a sub-fragment(ClickedMatch).

I am trying to pass a variable from MatchAdapter to ClickedMatch.

Comment: your context is null on statement PassAdapterVariable passAdapterVariable = (PassAdapterVariable) context;, move this to yout adapter class constructor.

Comment: I moved the PassAdapterVariable passAdapterVariable = (passAdapterVariable) context. I have two constructors (not sure if that is good practice), when I place it isn the second constructor I get the same NPE. When I place it in the first constructor, the program crashes and I get the error message User Main Page (which is the main activity) cannot be cast to MatchAdapter.PassAdapterVariable. @darwin

Comment: did u Implemented the PassAdapterVariable interface in your Activity?

Comment: You must use the constructor with arguments from your activity and implement your PassAdapterVariable interface in the same activity

Comment: No, I have only implemented it in the fragment. Should I also implement it in the activity? @darwin

Comment: if u r calling the adapter from the fragment then implement the PassAdapterVariable interface in ur fragment(ClickedMatch )

Comment: also use public MatchAdapter(List<String> maImg, int size, Context context, DiscoverPage discoverPage) constructor in ur fragment instead of  public MatchAdapter(String mname)

Comment: To add some context, I have a main activity (UserMainPage). A bottom navigation menu selector replaces the UserMainPage with a fragment(DiscoverPage). DiscoverPage calls the adapter(MatchAdapter). A button click on DiscoverPage replaces DiscoverPage with a sub-fragment(ClickedMatch). As suggested I implemented the interface in DiscoverPage and I get a cast exception "UserMainPage cannot be cast to MatchAdapter.PassAdapterVariable". @darwin

Comment: you should implement PassAdapterVariable interface in ClickedMatch fragment and call  MatchAdapter matAdapter = new MatchAdapter(maImg,size,contecxt,discoverPage);

Comment: I did as suggested. It's still not working. I either get a NPE or a cast exception. If passVariableAdapter is initialized in the constructor I get a cast exception. If it is initialized outside the constructor I get a NPE. @darwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to pass data from an adapter to a sub-fragment using a `Bundle`.

I modified my code as follows:

In the adapter I added:

```
fragment = new ClickedMatch();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("matchname",mname);
fragment.setArguments(bundle); 

...

transaction.commit();
```

In my sub-fragment I added:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if(bundle != null){
   pname = bundle.getString("matchname");
}
```

There was no need to use an interface. Based on what I have researched I think (and I may be wrong) that creating an interface and then implementing it is better used when communicating between fragments as opposed to communicating between an adapter and a sub-fragment.

Comment: i tried your code but value is not going to another fragment

Comment: @Adnanhaider I am not sure in what context you tried the code, but it worked for me (3 years ago) without any issues. There are other recommendations in this post, perhaps you'll have success trying one of their suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the String "mname" is null when you call     passAdapterVariable.passAdapterVariable(mname);

Either you're List maImg is empty || null or the provided adapter position is wrong.

try logging

```
            Log.d(TAG, "pos: " + getAdapterPosition());
            mname = maImg.get(getAdapterPosition());
            Log.d(TAG, "name: " + mname);
```

Comment: List maImg is not empty. implemented the log as suggested and I get values 08-13 23:20:59.943 29966-29966/com.test.jack D/error: pos: 0
08-13 23:20:59.943 29966-29966/com.test.jack D/error: name: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jack-... @gekn76

Answer (score 0):

```
PassAdapterVariable passAdapterVariable = (PassAdapterVariable) context;
```

Is just a declaration+Assignment statement in your adapter class. At this point in time, ***context*** is null.

The variable context is getting assigned only in your constructor. Assign your ***passAdapterVariable*** after the ***context*** has been assigned

```
public MatchAdapter(List<String> maImg, int size, Context context, DiscoverPage discoverPage) {

        this.maImg = maImg;
        this.context = context;
        this.discoverPage = discoverPage;
        this.size = size;
        passAdapterVariable = (PassAdapterVariable) context;

    }
```

Comment: I assigned the passAdapterVariable after the context and I still get the NPE. @Arun Shankar

Comment: Can you post the changed code? Let me edit my answer to show what i meant better

Comment: I did try that. When I initialize passAdapterVariable there, the program crashes and I get a cast exception. 'UserMainPage cannot be cast to MatchAdapter.PassAdapterVariable".  @Arun Shankar

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add Context parameter in constructor of Adapter with String  as

       public MatchAdapter(String mname, Context context) {
             this.context = context;
        }

Now get the context from Fragment as 
MatchAdapter matAdapter = new MatchAdapter(pname, getActivity());
matAdapter.passAdapterVariable = this;
passAdapterVariable(pname);
txt_matchname.setText(tname);

return view;
```

Comment: Tried as suggested. I still get the NPE. I've posted updated code and added some more context to the question. @Sushil Chaudhary

Answer (score 0):

Inside MatchAdapter------
Add instance to your interface in constructor that will work as

```
{
DataInterface passInterface;
Context context;
public MatchAdapter(String mname, Context context1, DataPass pass) {

        this.passAdapterVariable  = mname;
        this.context = context1;
        this.passInterface = pass;
    }
}
```

Now get the instance of that interface while calling adapter as

```
{

MatchAdapter matAdapter = new MatchAdapter(pname, getActivity(),this);
}
```

Comment: When I add DataInterace passInterface I get the message "can't recognize symbol DataInterface". I cannot write "this.passAdapterVariable = mname". They are incompatible types. @Sushil Chaudhary

Comment: DataInterface is the interface you created write the class name you gave for interface and initialize passAdapterVariable before constructor as
String passAdapterVariable; use it

Comment: Check it out @RookyCoder